# npm start missing client id and client secret. without deburg Visual Code. Can I change to npm start?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Visual Code without deburg, i tried to type "npm start" it failed, throw a notice "Missing script start". After  i changed "start": "node start.js", it throw a fialure notice "Missing FORGE_CLIENT_ID or FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET env. variables."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The app is throwing that error because the **forge credentials** (FORGE_CLIENT_ID and FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET) are **missing**.
You can **set/export** your forge credentials on your **terminal**.

Execute the following commands on your terminal.

In **Windows**:

```
   set FORGE_CLIENT_ID=<your client id>
   set FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET=<your client secret>
```

In **Linux** and **MacOS**:

```
   export FORGE_CLIENT_ID=<your client id>
   export FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET=<your client secret>
```